# How to Use Generic List for Multiple Purpose in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have done something like;

```
var list; //-> i want to declare this list once time
if (gvd.ID.Equals("gvAccountSetup"))
{
    ClsAccountHead AccountHead = new ClsAccountHead();
    AccountHead.CampusId = cmbAccCampus.SelectedValue.ToInt32();
    // here i want to intialize the same list with other type
    list = new List<ClsAccountHead>();
    list = AccountHead.AccountHeadListByCampusId(PageIndex + 1, PageSize);
}
else if (gvd.ID.Equals("gv_AccSubHead"))
{
    ClsAccountSubHead AccountSubHead = new ClsAccountSubHead();
    AccountSubHead.HeadId = cmbSrchAccHead.SelectedValue.ToInt32();
  // here i want to intialize the same list with another type
    list = new List<ClsAccountSubHead>();
    list = AccountSubHead.SubHeadGetListByHeadIdWithPaging(PageIndex, PageSize);
}
```

So, my Question is **How do i write a list(generic) which is declared once and then i can pass multipe type with it**;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a "tag" ineterface and made all your classes implementing it, and:

```
internal interface TagInterface { } // rename it as appreciated

public class MyList<T> : List<T> where T : TagInterface { }

var list = new MyList<ClsAccountHead>();
```

OR very simply:

```
var list = new List<TagInterface>();
```

Comment: How to make TagInterface...??

Comment: Plz can u send me Interface

Comment: @ShahidIqbal I modified the answer

Answer (score 1):

Just use a base class or interface of the items as the `List`'s `T`

```
var list = new List<BaseAccountHead>();
```

And make sure your types extend this type:

```
class BaseAccountHead { }
class ClsAccountHead : BaseAccountHead { }
class ClsAccountSubHead : BaseAccountHead { }
```